# Formula for conversion scale starting from 1 to percentages.

Tags: percentages

so my question is.

I have a scale ranging from 1 to 7 points. With 1 point beeing the worst and 7 points beeing the best. I need to convert this scale to percentages. E.g. 1 is 0%, and 7 is 100%

Can anybody help me out with the formula for coversion of this scale. For example 5 needs to be converted.
The problem that i run into is that 1 has to be 0%

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with $1$ going to $0\%$?  Intuitively, you can just subtract $1$ from your numbers so they run from $0$ to $6$.  Now you want $6$ to  be $100\%$.  Your percentage is $16.6666666 (\text{number}-1)$